# Is `Serial` field in `/proc/cpuinfo` unique for each Android device?

Tags: android, cpu

My question is in subject: when we read `/proc/cpuinfo` virtual file on Android, it contains `Serial` field. What is the value? Is it the same for all devices that use the same CPU model, or it is unique for each CPU instance?
I have GT-I9500 (Samsung Galaxy S4) phone, and its serial last 8 characters are `4d00a804` (revision is `000a`). Maybe anyone can write his last 8 characters for the same model to check if they are unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serial` is some number optionally passed by the bootloader and has nothing to do with the CPU. If set, the kernel treats it as unique for the device.

I have several devices with unset serial number (`0000000000000000`) and ARM64 and non-ARM devices do not have `Serial` at all.