# Obtaining any unique number from Android device without JNI - NDK only

Tags: android, android-ndk, unique, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to obtain aby unique number of the device from Android, NDK only.
I'd like to ask if there is such a way to do that.
I've tried these

- [Serial number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560841/is-serial-field-in-proc-cpuinfo-unique-for-each-android-device) in proc/cpuinfo, but found out it's not unique.
- [ANDROID_ID](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/0AiE_ohuUjM/EbzQpVWGG3sJ) - but couldn't use without JNI

Do you have any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I know it's been a while - but did you find a mechanism to uniquely identify devices from NDK only?